Redefining cleverefs multirangeformat for line numbers of listings
I would like to redefine cleverefs \crefrangeformat and probably also \crefmultirangeformat for the line numbers of a listings package. Consider e.g. the MWE below
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}, frame={tb}}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
for i = 1:10
    do stuff (*@\label{lst: line 1}@*)
    ...
    Intermediate stuff (*@\label{lst: line 2}@*) 
    ...
    do more stuff (*@\label{lst: line 3}@*)
end 
\end{lstlisting}


As we see in \cref{lst: line 1,lst: line 2,lst: line 3}
\end{document}


The output is somewhat as expected: As we see in Lines 2, 4 and 6
Which may be fine in most cases. However, I would like to get the output as a range: As we see in Lines 2 to 6.
The syntax for equations is quite known to me, e.g.
\crefrangeformat{equation}{#3(#1)#4 -- #5(#2)#6}

However, I do not know the correct key to put in instead of equation. I have tried lstnumber to no success, and also have not found the corresponding key for line numbers of lstlistings in the documentation of the listings package.
So, does anybody know the correct key to use?

Welcome! The equivalent of equation here is line, but cleveref will not turn a reference to lines 2, 4 and 6 into a range because the numbers are not consecutive.

line is the name of the relevant counter. However, the real issue here is that lines 2, 4 and 6 are not consecutive. If you want to refer to lines 2-6, you need to use \crefrange{}{} explicitly. If you refer to three consecutive lines, the compression is automatic so \cref{} is sufficient.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}

\lstset{escapeinside={(*@}{@*)}, frame={tb}}
\crefformat{line}{#2line #1#3}
\crefrangeformat{line}{lines #3#1#4--#5#2#6}
\crefmultiformat{line}{lines #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}{, #2#1#3}{ and #2#1#3}
\crefrangemultiformat{line}{lines #3#1#4--#5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4--#5#2#6}{, #3#1#4--#5#2#6}{ and #3#1#4--#5#2#6}
\begin{document}

\begin{lstlisting}
for i = 1:10
    do stuff (*@\label{lst: line 1}@*)
    ...
    Intermediate stuff (*@\label{lst: line 2}@*) 
    ...
    do more stuff (*@\label{lst: line 3}@*)
end 
\end{lstlisting}

As we see in the three non-consecutive \cref{lst: line 1,lst: line 2,lst: line 3}, \dots{}, but if we consider \crefrange{lst: line 1}{lst: line 3} as a whole, it is clear that \dots{}.

\begin{lstlisting}
for i = 1:10
    do stuff (*@\label{lst: line 1a}@*)
    Intermediate stuff (*@\label{lst: line 2a}@*) 
    do more stuff (*@\label{lst: line 3a}@*)
end 
\end{lstlisting}
As we see in the three consecutive \cref{lst: line 1a,lst: line 2a,lst: line 3a}, \dots{}, but if we consider \crefrange{lst: line 1a}{lst: line 3a} as a whole, it is clear that \dots{}.
\end{document}


Thank you! \crefrange{}{} was sufficient. But it is also good to know the name of the counter for \crefrangeformat.

@LaTeChiMan If you look in the .aux file, it is fairly easy to spot the pattern. Probably easiest with a small example combining a reference with a known counter and one with the counter you want to identify. You can just read it off from the lines cleveref adds which are all labelled.

Yeah, that would require not using Overleaf of course. Anyway, that is useful to know for the next time I want to redefine the behaviour of cleveref

@LaTeChiMan You can view the .aux file from Overleaf, although I found I had to download it rather than viewing it inline and it rather annoyingly named the file output.aux. (But I didn't try very hard to find an alternative - just went with the obvious route.) As far as I can tell, you can view any generated file.
